# How to return a Task<T> without await

Tags: c#, async-await

Is it possible to return a task from a method which first calls multiple `Task<T>` returning methods and then returns some type that includes the results from previous calls without using `await`?

For example, the below is straight forward:

```cs
public Task<SomeType> GetAsync() => FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

However, I would like to do something like this:

```cs
public Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    var list = GetListAsync();   // <-- Task<List<T>>
    var count = GetCountAsync(); // <-- Task<int>

    return new SomeType // <-- Obviously compiler error
    {
        List  /* <-- List<T> */ = list,  // <-- Also compiler error
        Count /* <-- int     */ = count, // <-- Also compiler error
    };
}
```

Is it possible to do this without having to write:

```cs
public async Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    return new Type2
    {
        List = await GetListAsync(),
        Count = await GetCountAsync(),
    };
}
```

Comment: Calling `GetListAsync` starts a task, the return value will be generated sometime in the future, when you say `await GetListAsync()`, you are telling wait till that return value is received, so How do you expect to assign a value that will be generated in sometime in the future right now to a variable?

Comment: Why?  `async/await` was invented to make this more readable and manageable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Because I read that having multiple await is bad for performance. I try to await on last call

Comment: @TomVast I thought you were trying to avoid refactoring existing codebase, but that is a [wrong reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407306/11683) to do it.

Comment: @TomVast - you heard wrong. But maybe you want to overlap both tasks with `await WhenAll()` , depending on your app type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) together with [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
public Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    var list = GetListAsync();
    var count = GetCountAsync();

    return Task.WhenAll(list, count).ContinueWith(_ => new Type2
    {
        List = list.Result,
        Count = count.Result,
    });
}
```

**Edit**

As suggested in comments, you're better off just using `await`. I also advice to read the post linked by [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) - [Performance of Task.ContinueWith in non-async method vs. using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407306/11683)

Comment: Note that it will be throwing `AggregateException`s in case of errors. You will need to [unwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21520869/11683) it.

Comment: This works, but is it any better?  In what way?  The sane thing to do here is just use `await`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It could be depending on implementation. I am assuming he wants to `await` on `GetAsync` and have both `GetListAsync` and `GetCountAsync` run in parallel. Depends on what these 2 methods do though.. It probably would be easier to just do `await Task.WhenAll(...)`

Comment: @HenkHolterman That requires declaring `GetAsync` as `async`, which in turn will make all its callers async etc. Apparently the OP is trying to use async while not refactoring the existing methods to be async.

Comment: @GSerg: No, `async` only affects the method itself, not the callers. Either way it just returns a `Task`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Then it only moves the point of ugliness from this method one step up the chain, because the caller, not being `async`, will also have to cope without `await`.

Comment: It moves the discussion one step up. It changes nothing about how to write _this_ method.

Comment: This is a bad way of doing things, frankly; the original code in the question *that uses await* would be hugely preferable

Answer (score 8):

Frankly, the version already in the question is *correct*:

```cs
public async Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    return new Type2
    {
        List = await GetListAsync(),
        Count = await GetCountAsync(),
    };
}
```

I realize you asked "without using await", but: the hacks to avoid the await are *suboptimal*; in particular, you should *almost never* use `ContinueWith` - that is the legacy API, and the `Task` implementation is now optimized for `await`, not `ContinueWith`.

As for:

> Because I read that having multiple await is bad for performance. I try to await on last call

No; once you have *one* incomplete await, it pretty much doesn't matter how many more you have - they're effectively free. The issue of having one vs zero incomplete `await` is comparable to the `ContinueWith`, so : you're not gaining anything by avoiding the `await`.

Conclusion: just use the `await`. It is simpler and more direct, and the internals are optimized for it.

As a minor optimization, you might want to add `ConfigureAwait(false)`, i.e.

```cs
public async Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    return new Type2
    {
        List = await GetListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false),
        Count = await GetCountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false),
    };
}
```

Or if they should run concurrently, and the implementation supports it:

```cs
public Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    var list = GetListAsync(); 
    var count = GetCountAsync();

    return new SomeType
    {
        List = await list.ConfigureAwait(false),
        Count = await count.ConfigureAwait(false),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method does not accept tasks with different result types. All tasks must be of the same type. Fortunately this is easy to fix. The `WhenAll` variant bellow waits for two tasks with different types, and returns a task with the combined results.

```
public static Task<TResult> WhenAll<T1, T2, TResult>(
    Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2, Func<T1, T2, TResult> factory)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        }
        else if (t.IsCanceled)
        {
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetResult(factory(task1.Result, task2.Result));
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
public Task<SomeType> GetAsync()
{
    return WhenAll(GetListAsync(), GetCountAsync(),
        (list, count) => new SomeType { List = list, Count = count });
}
```

The advantage over the other solutions is at the handling of exceptions. If both `GetListAsync` and `GetCountAsync` fail, the task returned from `GetAsync` will preserve both exceptions in a shallow `AggregateException` (not nested in another `AggregateException`).

Btw this answer is inspired by a Stephen Cleary's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530170/11178549).